# Can't login to WordPress admin "No password entered"

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, passwords, admin

I'm working on a website, and every time I want to log in to the wp-admin I can't log in because I get a "No password entered" message (see screenshot). When I reset my password I can actually log in to the admin area.

Because my client needs to work with this website too, this is not a solution. But I wonder why I get this error message in the first place, when I actually have entered the (correct) username and password.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m734kbetwq92qho/Schermafdruk%202014-08-05%2009.59.52.png

Comment: Do you have any plugins enabled, especially ones that modify any user settings? Are you using https to log in? It sounds like something is destroying your form data before it can be used.

Comment: I installed some plugins, but ended up not using them. I uninstalled them. Let's see how it goes.